# QGIS offset line shows perpendicular tags issue

Tags: qgis, offset

I'm adding data to a road network using LRS. I am offsetting the data to show different lanes of the road. In the example below I only have data for 1 lane.

However, some of the data shows an additional perpendicular "tag" towards the original network line. At some scales the "tag" disappears if I change the dimension to "meters at scale". If there is data for multiple lanes, then the tag is showing of for the data for each lane. I have checked the network line (using Vector > Geometry Tools > Extract Vertices) and there are no additional vertices which could be responsible for this.[image: "Tag" extending towards original network line]

Comment: Does it help to check off  or change the layer's rendering properties simplify geometry settings?

Comment: @MrLando - you'll probably have better luck getting an answer if you can share the dataset.

Comment: @John I tried that but it didn't make a difference. Thanks though.

Comment: ** UPDATE ** I'm using 3.28.2 but it also occurs on 3.30.1... for giggles I've just loaded the project using 3.18.3 and guess what? No tags!  so I guess this must be a bug?

Comment: As mentioned by @Llaves - without a sample of your data, it's just guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: It wasn't me, it was QGIS!

I'm using 3.28.2 but it also occurs on 3.30.1... for giggles I've just loaded the project using 3.18.3 and guess what? No tags! so I guess this must be a bug? The tags also don't occur on 3.22.5 and 3.26.3.

Thanks all for your efforts.